# multiple intent in broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

So I am making an app that listens for Screen On activity in android. I have a broadcast receiver that receives `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON`. This receiver then starts an activity.

Everything works fine but it starts the activity even when the screen was on because of an incoming call.

This is my code.

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainScreenActivity.class);
    i.putExtras(intent);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);

    Log.e("receiver", "throwing in the lock screen");
}
```

I am not quite sure how to I check the current state of the phone.
I have the permission to read `PHONE_STATE` but how do I find out if the sceen on action was fired because of the call?

Also there is a delay when the screen is actually turned on and the activity is displayed. The default lock screen is visible for a short time and then the custom one appears. Is there anything that can be done to avoid this delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register another broadcast receiver which responds to call incoming state set one flag which you can check in your receiver Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON) if flag is already set then skip to starting activity and reset flag else start activity
like

```
if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"))
{
    if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                              TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) 
{
    incomingcall = true;
}
}
```

and check

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
if(incomingcall ==true)
{
    //skip the reciver and reset flag incomingcall = false;
}
else{
Intent i = new Intent(context, MainScreenActivity.class);
i.putExtras(intent);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);

Log.e("receiver", "throwing in the lock screen");
}
}
```

for more information about ordered broadcast 
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html

Comment: Gaurav I think `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` is fired before `PHONE_STATE`. You know the order they get fired?

Comment: you can not be sure which intent gets triggered first at maximum you can set priority to your intent. Have you tried this code i think it should work.

Comment: from documentation on developer.android                        Ordered broadcasts (sent with Context.sendOrderedBroadcast) are delivered to one receiver at a time. As each receiver executes in turn, it can propagate a result to the next receiver, or it can completely abort the broadcast so that it won't be passed to other receivers. The order receivers run in can be controlled with the android:priority attribute of the matching intent-filter; receivers with the same priority will be run in an arbitrary order.

Comment: well that seem to have fixed the incoming call problem.